# Titan: Count edge with different propeties

Tags: titan

```
    Vertex u1 = g.addVertex(null);
    Vertex u2 = g.addVertex(null);
    Vertex u3 = g.addVertex(null);
    Vertex u4 = g.addVertex(null);
    Vertex u5 = g.addVertex(null);
    Vertex u6 = g.addVertex(null);
    Vertex u7 = g.addVertex(null);
    Edge addEdge = u1.addEdge("testRate",page);
    addEdge.setProperty("testRating", 1);
    Edge addEdge1 = u2.addEdge("testRate",page);
    addEdge1.setProperty("testRating", 2);
    Edge addEdge2 = u3.addEdge("testRate",page);
    addEdge2.setProperty("testRating", 1);
    Edge addEdge3 = u4.addEdge("testRate",page);
    addEdge3.setProperty("testRating", 3);
    Edge addEdge4 = u5.addEdge("testRate",page);
    addEdge4.setProperty("testRating", 2);
    Edge addEdge5 = u6.addEdge("testRate",page);
    addEdge5.setProperty("testRating", 2);
    Edge addEdge6 = u7.addEdge("testRate",page);
    addEdge6.setProperty("testRating", 1);
```

To get number of rating-1

```
page.query().direction(Direction.IN).labels("testRate").has("testRating", 1).count();
```

Now for geting all different kind of rating shall I execute the same kind of code or Is there some other way?

I found some `groupCount()` gremlin method. Is that what i need, is there any same way in java also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this worked:

```
  HashMap<Integer,Number>itemCount = new HashMap<Integer,Number>();
  GremlinPipeline<Vertex,Edge> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<Vertex,Edge>();
  pipe.start(v).inE("testRate").property("testRating").groupCount(itemCount).iterate();
  Iterator<Integer> iterator = itemCount.keySet().iterator(); 
  while(iterator.hasNext()) { 
      Integer next = iterator.next(); 
      System.out.println(next+"------"+itemCount.get(next));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `groupCount` would be a better way for several reasons:

1. It is clear - your intention to get a count of each rating type is
   evident in the code which makes readability nice for yourself and
   others
2. It is future proof - in other words, if you hard-code the
   `has` for each rating level (1,2,3, etc) if you ever add another
   rating level you will have to come back and add another "count"
   traversal.
3. I think it might end up being more efficient for you as
   vertex query isn't going to help because you intend to iterate all
   the `testRate` edges anyway.  Why not do it in a single traversal.

Comment: where is `groupCount` method in java API.I could not found any `groupCount` method in java API.

Comment: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/blob/master/gremlin-java/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/java/GremlinPipeline.java#L955

Comment: i did this `GremlinPipeline<Vertex,String> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<Vertex,String>();
        pipe.start(v).in("testRate").property("testRating").groupCount(itemCount).iterate();
        Iterator<String> iterator = itemCount.keySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            String next = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(next+"-------"+itemCount.get(next));
        }`

Comment: it just printing `null-------7` I was expecting result rating wise e.g `testRating 1` count is 3 so it should show `3` for `testRating 1`

Comment: You typically get a null when "testRating" returns `null`.  Remove the `groupCount` and see what returns from the `property` step.  If you are getting nulls then that's why the `groupCount` is counting it as such.

Comment: its printing `null` 7 times

Comment: shouldn't your code be `pipe.start(v).inE("testRate")`? the `testRate` property is on the edge not the vertex, right?

Comment: yah `testRate` is on the edge.its edge